# I was trying to run a simple code of c in VS ,but this shows,what to do?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image: I was trying to run a simple code of c in VS, but this shows, what to do???]
I was trying to run a simple code of c in VS ,but this shows,what to do???

Comment: Please post the code and errors as text -  [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Rename your `132.c` to `Main.c` and see if it works.

Comment: Change the code runner setting “save file before run” and also rename your file name.

Answer (score 0):

You selected the wrong project type. If the linker expects `WinMain()`, you are building a Windows GUI program. But your source is for a Console program.

Answer (score -2):

Try re-installing mingw62,gcc-g++

Comment: This answer is way too trivial. Also, reinstalling them is not an option to fix the issue.